# Custom OrderBy in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two columns that need to be sorted in a custom way.

For Eg: 
`Month` Column  it should be sorted in a way that `Jan2015` to `Dec(CurrentYear)`

and Also suppose I have Column as Quarter and I want it to or Order by as `Q1-2015`,`Q2-2015`,... `Q4-CurrentYear` ..

in orderby of Spark Sql I'll be giving as `orderBy("Month","Quarter")` but the Order should be Custom Sequence As before .

I have tried the code below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode 
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
val vDF=spark.sql(""" select month,quarter from table group by month,quarter order by month,quarter """);
vDF.repartition(10).orderBy("Month","Quarter").write(results‌​.csv);
```

As of now the Month gets Ordered as **Apr,Aug,Dec**.... in a alphabetical way and Quarter as **Q1-2015,Q1-2016**,.... but the requirement is the mentioned above

[image: SAMPLE]

Answer (score 2):

I'd just parse the dates:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  ("Jul", 2017"), ("May", "Q2-2017"),
  ("Jan", "Q1-2016"), ("Dec", "Q4-2016"), ("Aug", "Q1-2016")
 ).toDF("month", "quater")

df.orderBy(unix_timestamp(
  concat_ws(" ", col("month"), substring(col("quater"), 4, 6)), "MMM yyyy"
)).show()

+-----+-------+                                                                 
|month| quater|
+-----+-------+
|  Jan|Q1-2016|
|  Aug|Q1-2016|
|  Dec|Q4-2016|
|  May|Q2-2017|
|  Jul|Q3-2017|
+-----+-------+
```